# Bigquery %Like% grouping

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table that has a list of product names. I need to take a count of each product. some of the product names are written in different cases eg: "Juice" product - Juice, juice, etc. I need to group these together and show the count using bigquery

Juice - 100
juice-14
Milk -10
milk-3
mil-1

Above table has to be shown as below

Juice - 114
Milk - 14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If not misspelled words that you want to consider – solution would be as simple as below

```
SELECT LOWER(word) AS word, SUM(cnt) AS cnt 
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY 1
```

But in your case you need to deal with similarity first
Check below for the option to consider

First let's walk through high level logic/steps

> Step 0 - Assume your table (YourTable) is as below

```
SELECT
  word, cnt
FROM
  (SELECT 'Juice' AS word, 100 AS cnt),
  (SELECT 'juice' AS word, 14 AS cnt),
  (SELECT 'Milk' AS word, 10 AS cnt),
  (SELECT 'milk' AS word, 3 AS cnt),
  (SELECT 'milkk' AS word, 1 AS cnt),
  (SELECT 'mil' AS word, 1 AS cnt)
```

> Step 1 – Calculate similarity

let’s consider only those which have similarity between 0.5 and 1
So, expected result would be something as below

```
word    replacement similarity   
milkk   milk        0.8  
mil     milk        0.6666666666666667   
milkk   mil         0.6
```

> Step 2 - Find winners

You would expect:

```
word    replacement  
milkk   milk     
mil     milk
```

> Step 3 – Final Aggregation

```
word    cnt  
juice   114  
milk    15
```

> Below is respective code

Most likely can be optimized, improved and combined – but it is here the way it is to give you an idea (and working code)

> Query 1 (Step 1) - replacement candidates

Let's write output to table --> Replacements

```
SELECT text1 AS word, text2 AS replacement, similarity FROM 
JS(
// input table
(
  SELECT 
    word1 AS text1, 
    word2 AS text2
  FROM (
    SELECT
      CASE WHEN a.cnt < b.cnt THEN a.word ELSE b.word END AS word1,
      CASE WHEN a.cnt < b.cnt THEN b.word ELSE a.word END AS word2
    FROM (
      SELECT LOWER(word) AS word, SUM(cnt) AS cnt 
      FROM YourTable
      GROUP BY 1
    ) AS a
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT LOWER(word) AS word, SUM(cnt) AS cnt 
      FROM YourTable
      GROUP BY 1
    ) AS b
    WHERE a.word <= b.word 
  )
) ,
// input columns
text1, text2,
// output schema
"[{name: 'text1', type:'string'},
  {name: 'text2', type:'string'},
  {name: 'similarity', type:'float'}]
",
// function
"function(r, emit) {

  var _extend = function(dst) {
    var sources = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    for (var i=0; i<sources.length; ++i) {
      var src = sources[i];
      for (var p in src) {
        if (src.hasOwnProperty(p)) dst[p] = src[p];
      }
    }
    return dst;
  };

  var Levenshtein = {
    /**
     * Calculate levenshtein distance of the two strings.
     *
     * @param str1 String the first string.
     * @param str2 String the second string.
     * @return Integer the levenshtein distance (0 and above).
     */
    get: function(str1, str2) {
      // base cases
      if (str1 === str2) return 0;
      if (str1.length === 0) return str2.length;
      if (str2.length === 0) return str1.length;

      // two rows
      var prevRow  = new Array(str2.length + 1),
          curCol, nextCol, i, j, tmp;

      // initialise previous row
      for (i=0; i<prevRow.length; ++i) {
        prevRow[i] = i;
      }

      // calculate current row distance from previous row
      for (i=0; i<str1.length; ++i) {
        nextCol = i + 1;

        for (j=0; j<str2.length; ++j) {
          curCol = nextCol;

          // substution
          nextCol = prevRow[j] + ( (str1.charAt(i) === str2.charAt(j)) ? 0 : 1 );
          // insertion
          tmp = curCol + 1;
          if (nextCol > tmp) {
            nextCol = tmp;
          }
          // deletion
          tmp = prevRow[j + 1] + 1;
          if (nextCol > tmp) {
            nextCol = tmp;
          }

          // copy current col value into previous (in preparation for next iteration)
          prevRow[j] = curCol;
        }

        // copy last col value into previous (in preparation for next iteration)
        prevRow[j] = nextCol;
      }

      return nextCol;
    }

  };

  var the_text1;

  try {
    the_text1 = decodeURI(r.text1).toLowerCase();
  } catch (ex) {
    the_text1 = r.text1.toLowerCase();
  }

  try {
    the_text2 = decodeURI(r.text2).toLowerCase();
  } catch (ex) {
    the_text2 = r.text2.toLowerCase();
  }

  emit({text1: the_text1, text2: the_text2,
        similarity: 1 - Levenshtein.get(the_text1, the_text2) / the_text1.length});

  }"
)
WHERE similarity > 0.5 AND similarity < 1
ORDER BY similarity DESC
```

> Query 2 (Step 2) – replacement winners

```
SELECT word, replacement FROM (
  SELECT 
    a.word AS word, a.replacement AS replacement, b.replacement, b.weight,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.word ORDER BY b.weight DESC) AS win
  FROM (
    SELECT word, replacement
    FROM Replacements
  ) a
  JOIN (
    SELECT replacement, COUNT(1) AS weight
    FROM Replacements
    GROUP BY replacement 
  ) b
  ON a.replacement = b.replacement
)
WHERE win = 1
```

> Query 3 (Step 2 and 3 combined) - replacement and final aggregation

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(y.replacement, x.word) AS word,
  SUM(cnt) AS cnt
FROM (
  SELECT LOWER(word) AS word, SUM(cnt) AS cnt 
  FROM YourTable
  GROUP BY 1
) x
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT word, replacement 
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      a.word AS word, a.replacement AS replacement, b.replacement, b.weight,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.word ORDER BY b.weight DESC) AS win
    FROM (
      SELECT word, replacement
      FROM Replacements
    ) a
    JOIN (
      SELECT replacement, COUNT(1) AS weight
      FROM Replacements
      GROUP BY replacement 
    ) b
    ON a.replacement = b.replacement
  )
  WHERE win = 1
) y
ON x.word = y.word
GROUP BY word
```

Even though above works  - and you can run it through example – I cannot guarantee that this will work exactly as you expect with your actual data. But I hope this gives you a good direction to explore

Comment: Thanks Mikhail! I got an overall idea on how to approach my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
SELECT product_name, COUNT(*) from <table> GROUP BY 1 IGNORE CASE
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not just the case.. some are misspelled and have short name. basically i need to group similar words together and aggregate the count.

Comment: I want to know how can i achieve this using regular expresions